# can't change from address php mail

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use PHP `mail` to send emails from a contact form:

```
<?php 
   $email = $_POST["email"]; 
   $msg = $_POST["msg"];
   $msg = nl2br($msg);
   $msg = stripslashes($msg);
   $headers = 'From: email@example.net' . "\r\n" .
              'Reply-To: email@example.net' . "\r\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
   $to = "email@example.net"; 
   $mseg = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body style='font-family:sans-serif;'><div class='header' style='padding:20px;background:#dea544;border:2px inset #fff;'><h1>Tricks for the Web</h1></div><hr><div style='background:#dea;padding:1em'><p>$name contacted you. They left this message: </p><div class='msg-container' style='background:#fff;border:1px solid #000;padding:1.3em'><p class='msg' style='font-family:sans-serif;'>$msg</p></div></div></body></html>"; 
   $subj = "Contact"; 
   if(isset($_POST["copy"])){
       $o = $_POST["email"];
       $ss = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body style='font-family:sans-serif;'><div class='header' style='padding:20px;background:#dea544;border:2px inset #fff;'><h1>Tricks for the Web</h1></div><hr><div style='background:#dea;padding:1em'><p>Thanks for contacting us. Here's your copy of that message you left us. </p><div class='msg-container' style='background:#fff;border:1px solid #000;padding:1.3em'><p class='msg' style='font-family:sans-serif;'>$msg</p></div></div></body></html>"; 
       mail($to, $subj, $mseg,$headers); 
       mail($o, $subj, $ss, $headers);
       echo "Your message was submitted successfully. Please note that your copy may take time to reach you.";
   } else {
       mail($to, $subj, $mseg, $headers);
       echo "Your message was submitted successfully.";       
   } 
?>
```

The email gets sent, however the from address is still the default, it isn't the one that I set it to. Why isn't this working, and how can I fix this.
**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)**
**[Live Page](http://tricksfortheweb.net46.net/contact)**

Comment: You are overwriting your $headers variable here `$headers = "MIME-...`, change it to `$headers .=` like you have below it

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't notice that.

Comment: You can use any of 50 excellent mail libraries available for php - phpmailer, switfmailer etc

Answer (score 2):

When the host overwrites the `From:` header you can use the famous 5th parameter for mail:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f your@email.here");
```

I really suggest giving phpmailer or swiftmailer a try at some point.

Comment: I just overlooked a period, see above comment.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb ahh all good.